# How to call class function by parameter in python

Tags: python, class, parameters, arguments

Below is a sample code

```
def bar_2():
    print("inside bar 2")

class FOO:
    def __call__(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            arg()
    def bar_1(self):
        print("inside bar 1")


foo = FOO()
foo(bar_2)
```

Output: `inside bar 2`

But if I want to call `foo(bar_1)`

Output:  `NameError: name 'bar_1' is not defined. Did you mean: 'bar_2'?`

Is it possible to call bar_1 by parameter?

Comment: `foo(foo.bar_1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class methods can only be referenced with class object. So it can be like:

```
foo = FOO()
foo(foo.bar_1)
```

Comment: I think the naming isn't right here. Its not a class method, Those are created with the `@classmethod` decorator. You make use of an instance method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A instance method keeps a reference to its object. So you can do

```
foo(foo.bar_1)
```

To see the difference, `bar_1` is a function on the class but becomes a method on the instance

```
>>> FOO.bar_1
<function FOO.bar_1 at 0x7f0da7583d90>
>>> foo.bar_1
<bound method FOO.bar_1 of <__main__.FOO object at 0x7f0da756a080>>
```

Answer (score 1):

To access bar_1 by parameter, Please call it using the object `foo`.

```
def bar_2():
    print("inside bar 2")

class FOO:
    def __call__(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            arg()
    def bar_1(self):
        print("inside bar 1")


foo = FOO()
foo(foo.bar_1)
```

Output: `inside bar 1`